# HTML5 Video not working in IE 11

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video

I have a video archive that I have working in everything except IE 11. I get the error "Error: Unsupported video type or invalid file path" when loaded in IE 11. Below is the HTML I am using.

```
<video id="movie" width="640" height="400" autobuffer controls preload="auto"> 
                <source src="/media/Archive_Videos/September%202013/September_13_U-RUN.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
                <source src="/media/Archive_Videos/September%202013/September_13_U-RUN.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
                <source src="/media/Archive_Videos/September%202013/September_13_U-RUN.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
                    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf" width="640" height="360">
                        <param name="movie" value="http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf" />
                        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
                        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
                        <param name="flashVars" value="controlbar=over&amp;file=SITE%2Fmedia%2FArchive_Videos%2FSeptember%25202013%2FSeptember_13_U-RUN.mp4" />
                        <span title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below">September 2013 U-RUN</span>
                    </object>
                <p>OOPS! It looks like your browser doesn't support HTML5 videos. You can either install the latest version of your browser or download the video below:
                <br /><a href="SITE.com/media/Archive_Videos/September%202013/September_13_U-RUN.mp4">MP4 format</a> | <a href="SITE.com/media/Archive_Videos/September%202013/September_13_U-RUN.ogv">Ogg format</a> | <a href="SITE.com/media/Archive_Videos/September%202013/September_13_U-RUN.webm">WebM format</a></p>
            </video>
```

I also have an .htaccess file so it works in Firefox.

```
AddType audio/ogg oga ogg 
AddType video/ogg ogv
```

Why isn't it working in IE 11?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe IE requires the H.264 or MPEG-4 codec, which it seems like you don't specify/include. You can always check for browser support by using [HTML5Please](http://html5please.com/) and [Can I use...](http://caniuse.com/#feat=video). Both sites usually have very up-to-date information about support, polyfills, and advice on how to take advantage of new technology.

Comment: @shubniggurath `<source src="movie.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2"'>`

Comment: to work in IE we need to give <source src="movie.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs=" H.264/MPEG-4" '> is this correct

Answer (score 39):

What is the resolution of the video? I had a similar problem with IE11 in Win7. The Microsoft H.264 decoder supports only 1920x1088 pixels in Windows 7. See my story: http://lars.st0ne.at/blog/html5+video+in+IE11+-+size+does+matter

Comment: Wow, this is so stupid... Why they need to limit the size? Thank you for your post.

Comment: It's 48x48 up to 1920x1088. After Windows 7 higher resolutions are accepted but not guaranteed to be displayed.

Comment: Wow holy f-, i just had this bug, for me the problem was that the video i was showing was 1920x1077, it just showed a black screen. Then once i noticed the odd resolution and stretched it to 1920x1080, video works! Dear god Microsoft what the f- is going on under the hood that these sort of things happen?!?! Thanks everybody in this question for hinting me to look at resolutions, Microsoft; i hate you.

Comment: Thanks for this! I was spending hours in looking for solution

Comment: Glad that an 2 year old post still is still useful for someone else!

Comment: Had the same issue at widths of 1280px+ with H264 mp4. Have spend far too much time thinking it couldn't be the width. If you have the same problem on IE try shrinking your video!

Answer (score 6):

I've been having similar issues of a video not playing in IE11 on Windows 8.1. What I didn't realize was that I was running an N version of Windows, meaning no media features were installed. After installing the [Media Feature Pack for N and KN versions of Windows 8.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40744) and rebooting my PC it was working fine.

As a side-note, the video worked fine in Chrome, Firefox, etc, since those browsers properly fell back to the `webm` file.

Comment: Thanks.  Since I never fully resolved this, I may give that a shot.  Yeah, all other browsers are working fine for me too.

Comment: bah. spent 3 hours looking for the error. windows 7 n. thanks for your post.

Comment: Even installed Media feature pack didn't solve the issue for me on Windows 10 N

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but here is a additional thing if you still encounter problems with the solution above.

Just put in your `<head>` :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

It will prevent IE to jump back to IE9 compatibility, thus breaking the video function.
Worked for me, so if you still have problems, consider checking this out.

Alternatively you can add this in PHP :

```
header('x-ua-compatible: ie=edge');
```

Or in a .htaccess file:

```
header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge"
```

Answer (score 0):

Although MP4 is supported in Internet explorer it does matter how you encode the file. Make sure you use BASELINE encoding when rendering the video file. This Fixed my issue with IE11

Answer (score 0):

It was due to IE Document-mode version too low. Press 'F12' and using higher version( My case, above version 9 is OK)

Answer (score 0):

In my case Codec ID of mp4 file was the issue, Codec ID: isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
was not playing in IE 10 and 11 using video tag, after I converted it to "mp42 (mp42/isom/avc1)" using FFmpeg it started playing in IE as well.

Answer (score 0):

I used [MP4Box](https://github.com/gpac/gpac) to decode the atom tags in the mp4. (MP4Box -v myfile.mp4)  I also used ffmpeg to convert the mp41 to mp42.  After comparing the differences and experimenting, I found that IE11 did not like that my original mp4 had two avC1 atoms inside stsd.

After deleting the duplicate avC1 in my original mp41 mp4, IE11 would play the mp4.