# HTML5 video on IE11 not playing

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, video

I have searched a lot for this and found a lot of posts but none could help me.
I am trying to show a mp4 video like this

```
<video width="640" id="video1" controls="controls">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="~/Content/Videos/HelpVideo.mp4" />
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

But it always shows `Error: Unsupported video type or invalid file path` in IE11.

It works perfectly in firefox and chrome.

Even in IE11 when I right click on video and select `Copy Video URL` option then also it returned correct video URL which I get able to download and play properly.

The strange thing is when I try the same video in a sample project having only one html page and the same video in the same folder, it works in IE11 also!!

So can it be related to wrong path or something? I am using MVC4

I tried `@Url.Content("~/Content/Videos/HelpVideo.mp4")` for path but that also didn't work for IE.

I also tried adding mime type in project `web.config` file as well as `applicationhost.config` files

**Edit**

Just found in the network pan of developer tool of IE11 that mime type is going wrong for my videos, mime type is going `application/octet-stream` while it should be `video/mp4`

When I check this microsoft website for video support, http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/videoformatsupport/default.html it shows the correct mime types for videos i.e. `video/mp4`

So now the exact problem is known.

Comment: I think problem is mp4 format is not supported by IE11

Comment: But I think IE11 supports mp4 format. And as I said I have created a sample project in which the video works in IE11

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 Video not working in IE 11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124885/html5-video-not-working-in-ie-11)