# MP4 in HTML5 Video Tag Not Playing in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, video, mp4

Can anybody tell me why this is working for Firefox and Chrome, but not for IE9, 10, or 11? It's giving me the typical black screen with a small white square containing a red X.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML5 Video Player Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <video style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; height:100%; width:100%;" autoplay controls>
      <source src="./videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="./videos/video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

**Things I have already tried:**
- Adding the MIME type to .htaccess
- Re-encoding to make sure the MP4 are properly H264.
- video.js didn't help at all.

I have also tried just using 'File' > 'Open' and opened the MP4 locally on my machine using IE, and it plays just fine like that, so I think the video should be properly encoded and everything for IE.

Comment: Related post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21124885/1355856

Comment: When I was resolving this, I used a program called MediaInfo (there may be other tools too to introspect the exact codec version) and found that despite being MP4, my videos were using the "MPEG-4 Visual" codec, while the correct, most commonly-used H.264 codec should be titled "AVC". Do Firefox/Chrome still play the video if you temporarily remove the OGG source (to verify they are also using MP4)?

Comment: If I remove the OGG source, Chrome still works but not Firefox.

Comment: I tested with MediaInfo, and the MP4 are all using AVC.

Comment: Did you find any solution yet?

Answer (score -1):

For IE9 use meta tag something like

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to have helped any.