# MP4 video file doesn't play in HTML5 video player on Internet Explorer due to Encoding

Tags: html, video, internet-explorer-11

On a website i am using HTML5 to embedded a self hosted video without controls. I started out with a video file of 2mb and it played fine without problems in all browsers.

Recently I added a different video of 16mb. Now the video will play in all browsers except internet explorer. Does anyone have a clue how to fix this problem?

link: http://www.elephantdevelopment.nl/Startransfer/

HTML used:

```
<video id="myVideo" width="100%" height="100%"  loop>
    <source src="/Startransfer/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/startransfer-opening-home-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Video not working in IE 11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124885/html5-video-not-working-in-ie-11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. Although MP4 is supported in Internet explorer it does matter how you encode the file. Make sure you use BASELINE encoding when rendering for self hosted webvideo.