# Video HTML doesn't work on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-video

I try to display a full width video on a web page, but it doesn't work on IE 11.

html code :

```html
<div id="containerVideo">

     <video id="video" autoplay><source src="assets/videos/video1.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
        <source src="assets/videos/video1.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' /> 
        <source src="assets/videos/video1.ogg" type='video/ogg"' />
        Video not supported. 
    </video>

</div> <!-- fin Container Video -->
```

CSS code :

```css
#containerVideo {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1; 
}

#containerVideo video {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124885/html5-video-not-working-in-ie-11

Answer (score 1):

Audio and video must have the correct mime-type set on the server, [according to Microsoft themselves](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924821%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

[You may have to include a codec in the mark-up.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21126653/4384991)

There is a variety of alternative solutions out there, [EXAMPLE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7535006/4384991).

I've battled this problem myself, and ended up just using a quite offensive `poster` (completely discriminating IE users, well deserved though), as the problem itself differs in many cases depending on e.g. file formats and codecs. My best tip is really to [search around on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=html5%20video%20internet%20explorer), filter by date, and find out how others went around the problem or solved it.

This is definitely a duplicate question, but good luck though.