# IE html video tag gives black box

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, pjax

I am developing and webpage, where subpages are downloaded with pjax and dynamicly inserted into document. In few pages i have `<video>` tag as below:

```
<video poster="img/slide_1.jpg" autoplay muted loop>
    <source src="video/slide_1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video/slide_1.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

In Chrome and FF everything seems to work well. In IE (checked on v11) i get a box with dimensions of video but all filled with black.

I have tried turning off caching by adding query string parameter `?t=` with some random value, but got no effect. Thought resposne HTTP codes are relevant, but no matter if i got 200, 206, or 304, browser behavior was totally random.

When I hit the URL in the browser (normal GET request) i found no errors.

Does anybody have a clue, how to cope with that?

Comment: It is most likely the codec you have used is not available on your Windows. More useful information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124885/html5-video-not-working-in-ie-11

Comment: I am afraid it's not a case of codecs, because sometimes it works well, in a totally random way.