# Videojs: unable to play webm and ogv videos in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, video.js

I am currently implementing video playback my own application.
When I tried to play `WEBM` and `OGV` videos in `IE11` using `videojs`.

when doing that I am facing the error :

```
(CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) No compatible source was found for this media. [object Object]`.
```

But in Chrome and Firefox it is working fine. Is there is any way to sort out this issue in `IE11`.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this may be it helps u - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124885/html5-video-not-working-in-ie-11

Comment: https://www.webmproject.org/ie/

Comment: @Kaiido it seems webmproject is the software which i need to install in my system. but i need plugin like stuff which doesn't require any installation. Thing which i need to know is "is it possible to play webm/ ogv videos in IE using Videojs. if so, how?".

Comment: No, you need to install this plugin or an other one to be able to play webm in IE. If you want to support IE, then create a copy of your video encoded in H.264 and MP3 in a .mp4, according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats IE does support it.

Comment: @Kaiido you mean i need to convert the the webm and ogv video as encoded mp4 format?

Comment: That's about it yes...

Comment: OK Thanks Kaiido