# html5 video controls not working in ie11

Tags: jquery, html, css, html5-video

All my html5 video controls are visible and even hover effects are there but nothing happens on click. Play/Pause fullscreen slider buttons none of them are working, however **with tab I can control these buttons but not with click**

```
<video  controls id="videoId2" class="hide">
  <source ng-src="video/Help_role.mp4"  type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

From my js I am doing this to play

```
 var v=$($('#helpModal').find("#videoId2")[0]);
          v.removeClass("hide")
            v[0].play();
        });
```

**Note: My video is playing fine. Only the html5 video player controls are not working**

Comment: could you add some more details like what type of video you are using and better provide the code snippet also. Check out this one alsohttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124885/html5-video-not-working-in-ie-11

Comment: Updated my question. The link you shared is a different problem. I have no problem in playing my video.

Comment: so after some click function only your video is getting played?can you create an environment for the same and post here..btw check whether this is working in your IE11.https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video , it's working for me.