# HTML video tag does not work in IE 11 even after codec

Tags: html, html5-video, internet-explorer-11

I have video

```html
    <div id="video" style="--aspect-ratio:3/1;">
 <video autoplay muted loop>
  <source src="fotky/video.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs=" H.264/MPEG-4"'>
   <source src="fotky/video.ogv" type="video/ogv" >
  <source src="fotky/video.webm" type="video/webm" >
   <p>Váš prohlížeč nepodporuje video</p>
 </video>
</div>
```

And in IE 11 it does not show anything. I tried codecs like is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124885/html5-video-not-working-in-ie-11/21126653). But not even  `type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2"'` worked.

What can I do to make it work? Any different codec?

Edit:

```
<div id="video" style="--aspect-ratio:3/1;">
<video autoplay muted loop>
    <source src="fotky/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="fotky/video.ogv" type="video/ogv" >
    <source src="fotky/video.webm" type="video/webm" >
        <p>Váš prohlížeč nepodporuje video</p>
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove codec and pass the type with in double quotation works on my side in IE 11.

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="video" style="--aspect-ratio:3/1;">
 <video autoplay muted loop>
  <source src="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\SampleVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="fotky/video.ogv" type="video/ogv" >
  <source src="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" type="video/webm" >
   <p>Váš prohlížec nepodporuje video</p>
 </video>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Still it does not work. It behaves the same even with the codec and without.

Comment: Did you pass the type with in double quotes? Can you show your testing result and your modified code? I will again try to make a test on my side to check the result.