# Force loop for video in html4

Tags: html

I want to include mp4 video in a html page that launches automatically and then loops forever.

I am using the below code which I copied from an older project. (It's probably bad and outdated)

```
            <p><object id="MediaPlayer1" CLASSID="CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95" codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701" standby="Loading Microsoft Windows® Media Player components..." type="application/x-oleobject" width="1216" height="1216">
                <param name="src" value="ISS_1k_5sec.mp4">
                <param name="loop" value="true">
                <param name="fileName" value="ISS_1k_5sec.mp4">
                <param name="animationatStart" value="true">
                <param name="transparentatStart" value="true">
                <param name="autoStart" value="true">
                <param name="showControls" value="true">
                <param name="Volume" value="-450">
                <embed type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" src="ISS_1k_5sec.mp4" name="MediaPlayer1" width=1216 height=1216 autostart=1 showcontrols=1 volume=-450 loop="true"> 
        </object></p>
```

It launches and plays once but then stops. I can get it to play again by re-loading the page. But that's not the required functionality.

What's missing to make it loop?

FYI the page is there : http://skywatcher.space:8000/sun_2019/solar_campaign_2019.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1:**
Use HTML5 `<video>` tag.
For autoplay: `<video autoplay>`
For loop: `<video loop>`

Complete Code: 
`<video width="320" height="240" controls loop autoplay>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>`

[Visit this for details:](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp)

**Solution 2:** Upload video on youtube or vimeo and then embed it in your page. This will add autoplay and loop functionality in it.
for youtube: `<iframe style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8HSr8BjcufM?autoplay=1&controls=0&loop=1&playlist=8HSr8BjcufM&amp;showinfo=0" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>` [details](https://forum.webflow.com/t/youtube-embed-autoplay-loop-responsive-with-no-controls/25041)

For Vimeo: `<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871?autoplay=1&loop=1&autopause=0" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>` [Details](https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004485728-Autoplaying-and-looping-embedded-videos)

**Solution 3**
if you don't want html5 video tag and don't want to upload on youtube or other sites. You can use html video player libraries to add controls to it. Simple `<embed> or <frame>` tags have no controls. 
[to check IE compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124885/html5-video-not-working-in-ie-11)
[Internet explorer support for video tag](https://videojs.com/getting-started/#download-npm)